# Concept of introduce class, object?

Tags: android, arrays, string, class, listadapter

i'm new here so still very blur with some certain things here.
& i'm a bit confuse with following codes.

```
public class SmsActivity extends ListActivity { 
private String[] mSmsReceiver; 
public SmsActivity(){
mSmsReceiver = new SmsReceived();

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,mSmsReceiver));
```

### my understanding: (should be wrong)

line 1: Class `SmsActivity` under a superclass `ListActivity`
line 2: i introduce a string array term name:`mSmReceiver`
line 3: calling method `SmsActivity()`
line 4: inside `SmsActivity` method, `mSmsReceiver`(a string array) call method SmsReceived
line 5: `ArrayAdapter`(in string form, loaded with the info. of mSmsReceiver) loaded into `setListAdapter`

My question:

1. pls correct my understanding upon code above.
2. line 5, what is `this` refers to?
   (i checked on internet & books, it always says context. but i'm totally no idea what is context exactly means, anyone can explain what is context refering here?)

full codes:

```
    import...
    ....   

    public class SmsActivity extends ListActivity {
    private String[] mSmsReceiver;
    public SmsActivity(){
    mSmsReceiver = new SmsReceived();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main,mSmsReceiver));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //---method is call when listitem is clicked---
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {edit later});
    }


    private class SmsReceived extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {..... }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is a definition of a class named `SmsActivity`.

You are right about line 1 and line 2. More precisely, `mSmReceiver` is a private number of class `SmsActivity`.

Line 3 should be the constructor which I am not sure because I'm not an android developer and I heard it use `onCreate` instead in `Activity`. But anyway it wouldn't be `calling the method` just definition of it. The constructor will be used to initialize the class.

And line 4 `mSmsReceiver(a string array) call method SmsReceived`. Not the case, it would be `initialize mSmsReceiver with an object, which is an instance of class SmsReceived`.

Line 5 `this` refers to the class `SmsActivity`. In classes `this` almost always refers to the class it's in. And this provide a context so you can use `this.someMumber` or `this.someFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword "this" in Java is basically a reference to the Class that its in. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    MyClass myVar = this;
}
```

This will put an instance of the class MyClass in that variable. It gives you an instance of whatever class your in. If you call it in a method:

```
public void myMethod() {
    MyClass m = this;
}
```

This will give you an instance of whatever class invoked myMethod. Weather its an instance of MyClass or an instance of a subclass of MyClass. Whatever instance used to invoke the method will be placed in the m variable.

So when you call "this" in an Activity it gives you an instance of that Activity.

Comment: thanks. @JasonCrosby, a little small question here.
what if in `MyClass` i got few instance (A, B, C, D)
so in 2 code above, which instance will be loaded?  
is it randomly loaded? & each time different instance is loaded?